# Pull encrypted data from AWS SSM Parameter store into terraform var file and pass it encrypted till it is called inside the terraform code

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-secrets-manager, amazon-systems-manager, aws-ssm

How to pull encrypted data from the SSMParameter Store into the terraform var file and keep it encrypt end to end?

My requirement is:
I want to keep my passwords and some other environment variables in AWS SSM/AWS Secrets Manager, now pull that value into the environment variable in the encrypted form itself and finally decrypt it inside the terraform code. Any best way to do it?

Comment: If you decrypt it like this it will be visible as plain text in your state files. Its not a good practice.

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: The best way would be to decrypt it when you actually need it, in lambda or instance for example. Maybe if you explain your use-case, a detail answer can be provided.

Comment: The use case is, to keep all the Passwords and other data at one place, here we are planning to put in Parameter Store, now pull all those data into the environment variable in the local instance in encrypted form. Now, pass that in the terraform code where the variable is required in encrypted form as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a pretty simple script that uses AWS cli to pull the secret from secrets manager and sets it to an env var (local to that script) which then calls terraform plan and then terraform apply.  This snippet will grab a secret named `secret-name` from aws secrets-manager and then put it in an environment variable `TF_VAR_secret` (prefixing with `TF_VAR_` which will pass the var as the value of the terraform variable `secret`)

```
#!/bin/bash -e
set -o pipefail
set +x
export TF_VAR_secret=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:<AWS ACCT #>:secret:secret-name | jq -r .SecretString)
set -x
terraform plan
```

Keep in mind that using this pattern **won't** encrypt the value *in* terraform state. You'll want to make sure that whatever you're setting it to is marked as [sensitive](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/best-practices/sensitive-state.html#using-the-sensitive-flag) by the provider, as well as that wherever the remote statefile resides is encrypted at rest, and that access to read the state is appropriate for the data you have there.
See https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/sensitive-data.html

If you're using AWS codebuild, this gets way simpler by using an [`environment_variable`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codebuild_project#environment_variable) of type `SECRET_MANAGER`

To sum up:  your state should be encrypted, but **not**  values *in* the state. You solve this by encrypting the whole sate at rest and controlling access to state.  If a provider did encrypt values in state, [it would be pulled from the official registry](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/best-practices/sensitive-state.html#don-39-t-encrypt-state).